# How to write yml script to run the steps after pull request merge

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, devops, cicd

I have a `.yaml` file inside folder `.github/workflows/workflow.yml` to deploy the react app on github pages when a pull request is merged but it is failing saying `Invalid workflow file. You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 13`
Please help me

```
name: Github Pages Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'master'
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [15.x, 16.x]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Install and build
        run: npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps && npm run build

      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.1
        with:
          branch: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to
          folder: build # The folder the action should deploy
```

The line number 13 is this `if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true`

Comment: Did you tried setting [the ID for the job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-jobs-in-a-workflow#setting-an-id-for-a-job)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I haven't tried that but, if I remove line 13 `if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true` it works but I want the deployment to be done  only when the PR is is merged. Can you please suggest anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here.

```
jobs:
  if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [15.x, 16.x]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Install and build
        run: npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps && npm run build

      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.1
        with:
          branch: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to
          folder: build # The folder the action should deploy
```

The `if` statement has to be [inside of `jobs.<job_id>`(In this case it's `build`)](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif). So try to change it to

```
jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [15.x, 16.x]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Install and build
        run: npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps && npm run build

      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.1
        with:
          branch: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to
          folder: build # The folder the action should deploy
```